# Pandas: How to display a series value with brackets

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, series

I need to display the values of a series in brackets ().

```
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.Series (['12.1','23.2','30.3', '40.0'])
print (pd)
0    12.1
1    23.2
2    30.3
3    40.0
dtype: object

OUTPUT should look like here:
0    (12.1)
1    (23.2)
2    (30.3)
3    (40.0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `"("+pd.Series(['12.1','23.2','30.3', '40.0'])+")"`

Comment: Using the same name for an alias and variable is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to this but maybe you can add '(' ')' manually.

```
pd = pd.Series([f"({i})" for i in pd])
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.Series (['12.1','23.2','30.3', '40.0'])
print (pd)
0    12.1
1    23.2
2    30.3
3    40.0
dtype: object

pd=pd.apply(lambda i: f"({i})")
print(pd)
0    (12.1)
1    (23.2)
2    (30.3)
3    (40.0)
dtype: object
```